# regex pattern to not start with numbers but has to be alphanumeric with dash

Tags: html, regex

I'm looking for a html regex pattern to not accept numbers in the start of a string and no spaces but can allow alphanumeric with dash . Example " February-2023 " but not "2023February"

I tried the following patterns:

```
 pattern="^(?!0-9+)[a-zA-Z0-9\d\-]+$"
 pattern="^[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]*\S+$"
```

Comment: You can use: `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*$`

Comment: Just use a library like moment js or luxon to parse/validate date format, or see answer above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need hyphen/dash is mandatory, try this one: `^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*)+$`